# problems running mysql command from bash - copied from phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I receive the following error when I'm running it though BASH shell (ubuntu) - I copy/pasted this from `phpmyadmin` the command functions through phpmyadmin (below the following three command lines)

`ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1: Unknown column 'trash' in 'field list'`

```
mysql --user=user --password=password --database='wordpress' \
  --execute='UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_status`= 'trash' WHERE `wp_posts`.`ID`=56847;'
```

(works in `phpmyadmin`)

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_status` = 'trash' WHERE `wp_posts`.`ID`= 56847;
```

Comment: Are you sure you used the correct quotes? Your code example was a bit mangled, I've tried to fix it, but I may have missed something.

Comment: As a note, you do not have to delimit every single column or table name *unless* they conflict with a MySQL reserved keyword or contain irregular characters like spaces.

Comment: I think the problem are using single quotes for the sql statement. use double qoutes before UPDATE and on the end of your statement. So the shell knows that ```'trash'```is in the string

Comment: Thanks Tadman!  you got everything correct.

let me try run the command with different quotes

Comment: I changed the quotes to that - and I still received the same error